# get_option intermittently returns null when it should not

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am having an intermittent issue which is causing havoc on my wordpress site. Some conditional is occuring which causes get_option('home') and get_option('siteurl') to return null even though there is a value set for that option in the database. When this happens there are a number of unfortunate side effects which obviously causes the site to break aesthetically as well as functionally.

I suspect the issue may be occuring in the database layer and only lasts momentarily however the effects persist for a while due to heavy caching via w3 total cache and varnish (I am using w3tc db query caching). Has anyone ever encountered this issue before or have any insights? Am I running into a mysql locking issue?

Comment: Did you try disabling w3tc db query cache?

Comment: Yeah I had it disabled for a long time and still experienced the issue. It might also be useful to note that I use vaultpress, I noticed the problem this morning while vaultpress was doing something.

Comment: Disabled vaultpress yesterday but the problem still happened last night.

Comment: So I've still been unable to resolve this issue. It is an ongoing frustration to have a high traffic site go down with no apparent pattern. I've eliminated a number of things, one of which was the php-memcache extension. I used several different versions, eventually settling on the 2.2.x stable version - I read that later versions are horribly unreliable. I really suspect the problem is the mysql server as I have observed queries that should return quickly take way too long such as SELECT * FROM wp_options WHERE autoload = 'yes' during times when the server was under minimal load.

Comment: It appears that the mysql server becomes unresponsive intermittenly resulting in php requests to timeout and/or store corrupted data in cache causing terrible side effects. I would really appreciate any advice in troubleshooting this

Comment: Do you use VPS ?? Any other site in the server and do they have similar issue ??

Comment: No. Our servers are dedicated hardware. I've narrowed it down further. Turning off a particular custom plugin seems to make the problem go away but there is no explanation as to why the plugin creates the condition. The purpose of the plugin is to synchronize comments on facebook posts with articles on my website. The plugin does create a significant increase in sql queries although I do not feel that this is a bug or even unreasonable or why this would cause wordpress/mysql to behave in the manner i've described.

Comment: Not sure if anyone is still paying attention to this thread but I have an update. I've replaced w3tc object cache with memcached object cache to eliminate w3tc as the culprit. The issue has greatly improved however the problem has manifested with a brand new symptom. Now intermittently the rewrite rules get corrupted and many of our custom pages result in a 404. The solution is to flush the rewrite rules by visiting the permalinks page in the dashboard. It happened 3 times yesterday seemingly randomly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to upgrade the memcached daemon to version 1.4.11. Ever since I did that the problem went away so I guess I can chalk it up to version incompatibilities or bugs between php-memcache and memcached. My experience with memcached and it's various clients has lead me to believe it's quite touchy. I'm surprised given the very simple functionality it employs.